# Excel: Find matching values in 2 columns.

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

I have a spreadsheet with 2 columns. These columns have telephone numbers in them. I need a list of where the same telephone numbers exists in both columns. These need to be listed in column C as the matching telephone number.

Excel 2010.

Regards

Answer (score 5):

Look at the following screenshot, There is column A (A1:A15) and column C (C1:C13) which contain some duplicate names.

[image]

By using a formula, we can compare two columns and display the duplicate values. Please do with the following steps:

1. In cell B1, input this formula: “=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$13,0)),"",A1)”.

A1 is the column which you want to be compared.

$C$1:$C$13 is the range that you want to be compared with.

You can change the variables for what you are using.

2. Press the Enter key. Select cell B1, and then drag the fill handle over cell B15.
3. And all of the duplicate names will be displayed in column B. See screenshot:

[image]

just googled this

http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/774-excel-find-duplicates-in-two-columns.html

it does what you asked, takes duplicating values from 2 columns and puts them in a 3rd